# React Router component parameter vs child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference between

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
        <Welcome />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

and

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
</Switch>
```

Is it only a matter of style or they do different things?

Comment: both work same...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when you use the child approach you can pass props to the component being rendered instead when you use the component approach you just pass in the component but can´t pass any props to it (apart from the ones that are automatically passed when you render a component through a Route)

Comment: good point. Child syntax allows adding parameters. I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).

If we don't use inline functions in render this difference doesn't matter.